# Got Http response code 400 when Execute the paypal Payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I use paypal/rest-api-sdk-php package to process paypal payment. when success payment it's working fine. but, bank decline payment we got error.

[image]

```
$payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->apiContext);
    
            $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    
            $execution->setPayerId($request->PayerID);
    
            //Execute the payment
            $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->apiContext);
    
            if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
    
                $paypalPaymentInfos->payment_status=1;
    
                 $paypalPaymentInfos->transaction_id=$payment_id;
    
                $paypalPaymentInfos->save();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the response body to determine the reason for the 400 error. It could be a normal processing decline, or it could be something else.

The rest-api-sdk-php has been deprecated for a long time and uses the old v1/payments API. Do not use it for anything.

You should integrate with the v2/checkout/orders API for payment processing : use either the Checkout-PHP-SDK (which was also recently deprecated) or direct HTTPS integration with the REST API endpoints (no PHP SDK). For payer approval use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server rather than any redirect away from your site.